# Can I install ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 on a Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2160 @ 1.80GHz × 2

Tags: system-installation

I am running

```
a Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2160 @ 1.80GHz × 2
with 2 gigs of ram
with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit
```

Can I install ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso on this machine?
I am a new Linux user and am thinking the amd64 means its for a amd64 processor
Thanks in advance 
Jess

Answer (score 1):

[Intel has a page on this processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/29739/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2160-1M-Cache-1_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB).

According to it, that CPU does support the 64-bit architecture. So, yes, you can install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on your computer.

**Bear in mind:** If you were hoping to "upgrade" from 32-bit to 64-bit, well, you can't, at least not in a way that would take less time than a backup and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

[intel has prove this can be](http://ark.intel.com/products/29739/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2160-1M-Cache-1_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

This is possible to install 64 bit ubuntu on your machine.
Cheer.